# How to get only duplicate values from array

Tags: php

I need help with find items in array to show if some item is duplicate or more then 2 to show the result and I have been looking up for this too long now I need help from you guys.
this my array items

```
Array
(
    [0] => Array
        (
            [1] => 1:30am
            [2] => 2:00am
            [3] => 3:00am
        )

    [1] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2:30am
            [2] => 5:00am
            [3] => 6:30am
        )

    [2] => Array
        (
            [1] => 2:00am
            [2] => 3:00am
            [3] => 5:00am
        )

)
```

and have try it with `array_count_values()` it return

> Warning:  array_count_values(): Can only count STRING and INTEGER
>   values!

and with `array_unique` , `array_diff_assoc()` it return

> Notice: Array to string conversion

Please help, Thanks

Comment: its a multi-dimensional array, so you have to handle it appropriately! So you need to find each time and its appropriate count, am I right?

Comment: Whats the exact return you expect? An Arrray with count values or just the heighest occurence? Please specify your question

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Just for fun, here it is in just a few lines:

```
$values = array(
    array('1:30am', '2:00am', '3:00am'),
    array('2:30am', '5:00am', '6:30am'),
    array('2:00am', '3:00am', '5:00am')
);

$flatten = array();
array_walk_recursive($values, function ($item) use (&$flatten) {$flatten[]=$item;});
$duplicates = array_keys(array_filter(array_count_values($flatten),function($item){return $item>1;}));

print_r($duplicates);
```

Of course, readability is about zero.

The main takeaway is that you have to work with one dimensional arrays to use most of PHP's array functions. So somehow you have to flatten your multi-dimensional array first.

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
$unique = array_unique($array, SORT_REGULAR);
```

SORT_REGULAR makes sure that it will not use string comparison.

Answer (score 0):

You have to loop in your array, then loop again in your sub-arrays. From there, you can build an array with unique values, and an array with duplicates :

```
<?php 

$array = array(
    array('1:30 am', '2:00 am', '3:00 am'),
    array('2:30 am', '5:00 am', '6:30 am'),
    array('2:00 am', '3:00 am', '5:00 am')
);

$unique = $dupes = array();
foreach ($array as $subarray) {
    foreach ($subarray as $value) {
        if (!in_array($value, $unique))
            $unique[] = $value;
        else
            $dupes[] = $value;
    }
}

print_r(array_unique($dupes)); // Array ( [0] => 2:00 am [1] => 3:00 am [2] => 5:00 am )
```

Answer (score 0):

So to get count of every time, you can create a temporary array and make every time string as a key of that array and then increment its count like this:

```
$arr = [
['1:30am','2:00am','3:00am'],
['2:30am','5:00am','6:30am'],
['2:00am','3:00am','5:00am']
];


$countArr = [];

array_walk_recursive($arr, function($time) use (&$countArr) {
    if(array_key_exists($time, $countArr))   // If key exists, increment its value
        $countArr[$time]++;
    else                                     // Otherwise, assign new key
        $countArr[$time] = 1;
});

print_r($countArr);
```

That prints:

```
Array
(
    [1:30am] => 1
    [2:00am] => 2
    [3:00am] => 2
    [2:30am] => 1
    [5:00am] => 2
    [6:30am] => 1
)
```

---

Again, if you need to find the duplicates in that,

```
$duplicates = array_filter($countArr, function($value) {
    if($value>1)
        return true;
});

print_r($duplicates);
```

Will print:

```
Array
(
    [2:00am] => 2
    [3:00am] => 2
    [5:00am] => 2
)
```

Check for [EVAL](https://eval.in/720733)